# give different color to terms and conditions when we pass label in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a component called FormInput which looks like:

```
const FormInput = ({
  onChange,
  label,
  value,
  emailIcon,
  passwordIcon,
  ...props
}: FormInputProps) => (
  <GroupContainer {...props}>
    <FormInputContainer onChange={onChange} {...props} />
    {label ? (
      <FormInputLabel  {...props} className={value && value.length ? "shrink" : ""}>
        {emailIcon && <FormInputIcon src={emailIcon}/>}
        {passwordIcon && <FormInputIcon src={passwordIcon}/>}
        {label}
      </FormInputLabel>
    ) : null}
  </GroupContainer>
);
```

So, I wanted to pass label prop like this:

```
<FormInput
          type="checkbox"
          name="gender"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={() => setChecked((state) => !state)}
          label="Accept terms and conditions"
          checkbox={true}
          required
        />
```

I wanted to ensure that **label="Accept terms and conditions"** terms and conditions are in blue color. So, to achieve that I tried **label={`Accept ${<HighlightedLabel>terms</HighlightedLabel>} and ${<HighlightedLabel>conditions</HighlightedLabel>}`}** HighlightedLabel looks like this:

```
export const HighlightedLabel = styled.span`
  color: #0094ff;
`;
```

but the above way does not work since I get [object Object] rendered

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be add a property for the label style in `FormInput`:

```
const FormInput = ({
  onChange,
  label,
  value,
  emailIcon,
  passwordIcon,
  labelClassNames,
  ...props
}: FormInputProps) => {
const labelValueStyle = value && value.length ? "shrink" : "";
return (
  <GroupContainer {...props}>
    <FormInputContainer onChange={onChange} {...props} />
    {label ? (
      <FormInputLabel  {...props} className={`${labelValueStyle} ${labelClassNames}`}>
        {emailIcon && <FormInputIcon src={emailIcon}/>}
        {passwordIcon && <FormInputIcon src={passwordIcon}/>}
        {label}
      </FormInputLabel>
    ) : null}
  </GroupContainer>
  )
};
```

Use it:

```
<FormInput
          type="checkbox"
          name="gender"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={() => setChecked((state) => !state)}
          label="Accept terms and conditions"
          labelClassNames={labelColorStyle}
          checkbox={true}
          required
        />
```

Comment: hey  ), sorry I just wanted give styles to ONLY "terms" and "conditions", that is, I want to show Accept terms and conditions BUT I need to ensure that "terms" and "conditions" are in blue color